# possible to define sublimetext 3 config in path so to persist config to version control

Tags: git, sublimetext3

Is it possible to externalize my project-settings of Sublimetext 3 in a file located in the project dir so to persist the sublime settings to version control/git?

Comment: There is a such thing as a [sublime-project](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html) file which you could check into Version control, but it seems like it could be overridden by Syntax specific settings per the [settings doc](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html), and people would likely have to use the project file to get the benefit. [This blog](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-project-bliss/) is also interesting and applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sublime settings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html) are acquired in this order:

```
Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings
Packages/Default/Preferences (<platform>).sublime-settings
Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
<Project Settings>
Packages/<syntax>/<syntax>.sublime-settings
Packages/User/<syntax>.sublime-settings
<Buffer Specific Settings>
```

The [Project Settings](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html) from above are intended to be version controlled,

```
As a general rule, the sublime-project file would be checked into version
control, while the sublime-workspace file would not.
```

So yes you should be able to version control the json file and have it shared per project. HTH.